# Use curl to upload file avoiding form buttons

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, upload

I have this form:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And this php script:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
 {
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "/tmpupload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "/tmpupload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 }
?>
```

My goal is using curl from command line to upload a file.
The problem is to avoid the interaction with the button submit and choose, so the upload should me automatic.
Is there a solution?

Comment: So let me check, are you wanting the form to auto submit when a file has been selected?

Comment: Yes the auto submit can be a solution.

Comment: I just reread your question and noticed you are hoping to avoid the choose button too. How are you planning on selecting the file?

Comment: The file is directly selected by curl, I suppose.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, why are you trying to use an html form from the command line?

Comment: Because my application needs curl, it's a bash script.

Comment: why is there html in a bash script? o_0

Answer (score 0):

To make your form auto submit on selecting the file change your file input to look like

```
<input type="file" onchange="formname.submit();"  name="file" id="file" />
```

So make sure you give your form a "name" property and change 'formname' in the onchange to be the same as your chosen form name.